# Is there a way to generate a third category with the usage of .where or any other method?

Tags: python, numpy

I can get the two categories, but when I go and implement a third category with the additional coding, I come across an error.

Data:

```
Active                                 State/UTs
0        6                       Andaman and Nicobar
1    14550                            Andhra Pradesh
2      634                         Arunachal Pradesh
3     6415                                     Assam
4       55                                     Bihar
5       35                                Chandigarh
6      354                              Chhattisgarh
7        2  Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu
8      367                                     Delhi
9      885                                       Goa
10     152                                   Gujarat
11     617                                   Haryana
12    1699                          Himachal Pradesh
13    1286                         Jammu and Kashmir
14     126                                 Jharkhand
17      54                                    Ladakh
18       9                               Lakshadweep
19     125                            Madhya Pradesh
21    3180                                   Manipur
22    2104                                 Meghalaya
23   11414                                   Mizoram
24     712                                  Nagaland
25    6322                                    Odisha
26     914                                Puducherry
27     326                                    Punjab
28      86                                 Rajasthan
29     913                                    Sikkim
31    5505                                 Telengana
32     691                                   Tripura
33     227                             Uttar Pradesh
34     379                               Uttarakhand
35    8480                               West Bengal
```

code:

```
data2.insert(1, column = "Level", value = np.where(data2["Active"] > 9700, "Severe", data["Active"] < 9700 and data["Active"] > 4850, 'Less_Severe','Not_Severe'))
```

Output:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: use `&`, not `and`: `data2.insert(1, column = "Level", value = np.where(data2["Active"] > 9700, "Severe", data["Active"] < 9700 & data["Active"] > 4850, 'Less_Severe','Not_Severe'))`

Comment: This is not working out and I believe in python , there is the usage of 'and' instead of && (like in java).

Comment: in python yes, not in pandas. The`ValueError` is precisely because you use `and` in place of `&`. Then, there might be additional errors

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with np.select():

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Active':[10000,400,5000,12000,50,7000]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


col         = 'Active'
conditions  = [ df[col]<=4850, df[col]<= 9700, df[col] >9700  ]
choices     = [ 'Not_Severe','Less_Severe',"Severe"   ]
    
df["Level"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Active        Level
0   10000       Severe
1     400   Not_Severe
2    5000  Less_Severe
3   12000       Severe
4      50   Not_Severe
5    7000  Less_Severe
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a conflict? both 'Not_severe' and 'Less_Severe' are "fighting" for the label of the value. Should there be an usage of 'and' for 'Less_severe'?

Comment: No there is no conflit, because if the first condition is True, it's not checking the other. But if you prefer you can modify it by: conditions  = [ df[col]<=4850, df[col] > 4850 & df[col]<= 9700, df[col] >9700  ]